# is it possible to track an arbitrary skeleton model with the kinect?

Tags: kinect

I understand that the kinect is using some predefined skeleton model to return the skeleton based on the depth data. That's nice, but this will only allow you the get a skeleton for people. Is it possible to define a custom skeleton model? for example, maybe you want to track your dog while he's doing something. So, is there a way to define a model for four legs, a tail and a head and to track this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.  Using the Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK's skeleton tracker you are stuck with the one they give you.  There is no way inject a new set of logic or rules.

Long answer, sure.  You are not able to use the pre-built skeleton tracker, but you can write your own.  The skeleton tracker uses data from the depth to determine where a person's joints are.  You could take that same data and process it for a different skeleton structure.

Microsoft does not provide access to all the internal functions that process and output the human skeleton, so we would be unable to use it as any type of reference for how the skeleton is built.

In order to track anything but a human skeleton you'd have to rebuild it all from the ground up.  It would be a significant amount of work, but it is doable... just not easily.

Comment: I've updated the offending paragraph, and moved some sentences around, to hopefully better capture my intent.  Apologies for vagueness.

Comment: No problems. I've removed the (no longer) relevant comments.

Comment: Incidentally, the Kinect skeleton tracker uses no RGB data. It is easy enough to demonstrate this for yourself by taping over the lens of the RGB camera (or perhaps wearing a lot of camouflage!)

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to learn a bit about this subject by watching the dll exemple:
**Face Tracking**
from the sdk exemples :
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Where possible, it's best to try to summarize information in links in addition to providing them, as other websites can change and links can break. We want stack overflow to be a long-term resource.