# How can Kinect detect small figures

Tags: c#, c++, kinect

I've been trying to get the Kinect to put skeletons on small clay figurines about six inches tall, but have had no such luck.

I've moved the camera and figurine in different positions, made sure the figure is in detectable range, and even wiggled the limbs to get the Kinect to recognize the movements.

I'm using V1.8 on a Windows 10 and I'm wondering whether I can change something in the DepthStream class to recognize small figures.

I couldn't find such options in the API, so my approach could be entirely wrong.

**How could I get Kinect to recognize the skeleton?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly needs to be done to make this happen, but for starters the Kinect uses actual height to determine if something should get a skeleton, normally not associating one with anything under 3'.

So you're either going to have to lie to the SDK about the height of data or you're going to have to manually assign skeletons when you detect clay figures.

Comment: How could I lie to the SDK or manually add skeletons? I heard adding skeletons would require building the software from the ground up. Would lying be simpler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320926/is-it-possible-to-track-an-arbitrary-skeleton-model-with-the-kinect This told me custom skeletons are difficult to implement

Comment: @AlfredoVelasco In theory, you could add a constant to all the z values in the depth stream, so that the Kinect thinks the figurines up close are full-size people farther away.  But I don't know if the API gives you access to the raw data.

Comment: @piedar There's no way to change the raw data

Comment: So that's the hard answer for this question then. There's no way to directly manipulate the API to give you what you're looking for. Anything you want will have to be manually built.